# How do I create a Spring Boot Starter Project in Eclipse that is properly configured with a Run Configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I followed the instructions in [Spring Boot Support in Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4) and ended up with an Eclipse project which has several issues. The number one issue is that when I right-click on the class containing the "main" entry method and select the "Run As" option, the only entry I get is the fallback "Run Configurations..." method. I neither get the option to run it as a "Spring Boot App" or as a "Java Application".

My question is how do I create the project or what do I do after it's created following the instructions in that site to get that Run As option?

In addition to the above information, I should add the following:

- I'm using Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna SR2) and STS 3.7.1
- I've tried it on both Windows and Linux (Fedora with OpenJDK)
- Used Java 8 (Sun Hotspot 64-bit 1.8.0_65)
- When the pom.xml initially gets created, it has an error apparently due to a missing config the m2e wants for which I needed to add the following:

  ```
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
              <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
              <configuration>
                  <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                      <pluginExecutions>
                          <pluginExecution>
                              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                  <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                  <goals>
                                      <goal>compile</goal>
                                      <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                  </goals>
                              </pluginExecutionFilter>
                              <action>
                                  <ignore />
                              </action>
                          </pluginExecution>
                      </pluginExecutions>
                  </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  ```
- It doesn't look like the Eclise project is properly configured for a Java application either. There's no configuration for a Java src tree. Below is the .project file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <projectDescription>
          <name>demo</name>
          <comment></comment>
          <projects>
          </projects>
          <buildSpec>
                  <buildCommand>
                          <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                          <arguments>
                          </arguments>
                  </buildCommand>
          </buildSpec>
          <natures>
                  <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
          </natures>
  </projectDescription>
  ```
- I can manually run the app as per [How to run Spring Boot web application in Eclipse itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677808/how-to-run-spring-boot-web-application-in-eclipse-itself) (by executing [Project] --> Run As --> Maven Build... --> Goal: spring-boot:run

Comment: You may be hitting a problem with the Maven support in Eclipse/STS. I would recommend to download a fresh installation of STS 3.7.1 from http://spring.io/tools and try with that. It should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Believe me, don't ruin your Eclipse IDE with any plugin like that. Just use a different STS and everything will stay clean forever.

Answer (score 5):

To create a new spring-boot project in sts just click new spring-starter project, that will create the project for you. 
New->Project->Spring->Spring starter project

You'll run throught the wizard select 'Web' checkbox to have the web app selected
this will create an application class like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My auto generated POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I did (as per the site I linked to above), but the resulting project neither has the "Run As" configurations for the generated Java class nor does it even have a Java Build Path configured (or a Java facet/builder, for that matter). Is this a bug or something that I'm missing?

Comment: do you have java-8 installed?

Comment: Yes, using Java 8 all throughout

Comment: it should have generated a similar pom.xml file as mine. Whats the java version eclipse is using ? you can check this in Window->Preferences->Compiler

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with STS and Eclipse Luna (4.4.2). It seems to do the right thing in Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install the [Spring Tool Suite plug-in for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse). Then you'll see the "Spring Boot App" run configuration (and other STS features).

Answer (score 0):

After creating a Spring Boot application via the Spring Starter project via the menu need to do additional steps: Go into project properties and enable the Java facet. Then, right-click project and Maven > Update Project.