# New Spring Starter project is not working with maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using **Eclipse Luna** and installed **spring tool suite 3.7.3** release through eclipse market place.
 When I am creating a new spring starter project with maven the following error is coming and I am unable to proceed forward.

> Error: 'Import getting started content' has encountered a problem.
>           NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/model/Model

Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Some of the comments on this related question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484363/how-do-i-create-a-spring-boot-starter-project-in-eclipse-that-is-properly-config#33484453) indicate that eclipse luna has an issue with STS

Answer (score 0):

This sounds related to this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-3932. But I remember that we faced this issue again and implemented additional fixes and workarounds for this. Therefore I would recommend to use a more recent version of Eclipse/m2e/STS.