# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop...] is not valid

Tags: java, xml, web, servlets, server

I have a dynamic web project imported from Spring into Eclipse. I updated the server, it was embedded before, I updated the dependencies in the pom regarding the server, I read the other solutions regarding the various entries in the stacktrace, but nothing worked, I deleted .m2, the web.xml file I edited several times, some tutorials suggest creating a separate class for each jsp page, but this would no longer work for me a page that contains multiple forms and therefore refers to multiple methods in the class. However, I commented on the other servlets in the web.xml file because in the meantime I want you to load at least the first one that contains the references to all the others. I have been stuck on this error for several days. Can someone help me? thanks to who helps me.

The jar files contained in the Maven, do I have to copy them all in the WEB-INF \ lib folder?

do I need to add the pom.xml file here in the question?

STACKTRACE:

```
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.23
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 14 2022 08:16:11 UTC
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 10.0.23.0
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.2
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           18.0.2.1+1-1
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         
C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.
server.core\tmp0
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache2\apache-tomcat-10.0.23-windows- 
x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins
\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache2\apache-tomcat- 
10.0.23-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.23
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - 
Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins
\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0].
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random 
[true], UDS [true].
set 20, 2022 1:29:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022]
set 20, 2022 1:29:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 20, 2022 1:29:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [2187] milliseconds
set 20, 2022 1:29:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
set 20, 2022 1:29:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.23]
set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(
DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(
LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4834)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4972)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified 
[C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins\
org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Parlamento] is not valid
at 
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet
(StandardRoot.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 28 more

set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A 
child container failed during start
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(
DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during 
start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(
LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4834)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4972)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified 
[C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins\
org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Parlamento] is not valid
at 
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(
StandardRoot.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 28 more

set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(
DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during 
start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@74bada02]
at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException
(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4834)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4972)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(
InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(
AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified 
[C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\WORKSPACE3\.metadata\.plugins\
org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Parlamento] is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(
StandardRoot.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 28 more

set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
set 20, 2022 1:29:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                  https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
version="5.0">
<!--  
<display-name>Parlamento2</display-name> -->



<display-name>Parlamento</display-name>
<!--
<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
-->
<!-- 
<welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
           <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
class>   
    </welcome-file-list>
     -->
       
     <servlet> 
 <servlet-name>index</servlet-name> 
 <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet-class> 
 </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
   
    
    
      
     
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>parlamentari</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class> 
    </servlet>
    
     <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>parlamentari</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/parlamentari</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!-- 
    
    
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>lista_periodi_cariche.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>lista_periodi_cariche.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/lista_periodi_cariche</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
    
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>showParlamentare.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>showParlamentare.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/showParlamentare</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
    
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>parlamentareDeleted.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>parlamentareDeleted.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/parlamentareDeleted</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
    
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>lista_parlamentari.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>lista_parlamentari.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/lista_parlamentari</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>showParlamentare2.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
 class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>showParlamentare2.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/updateParlamentare</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>showParlamentare3.jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.giuggiola.controller.ParlamentareController</servlet- 
  class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>showParlamentare3.jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/getParlamentare</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     -->
    
 <!--  
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->
    </web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.giuggiola</groupId>
<artifactId>Parlamento</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bootjpa</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
    
    
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

    
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<version>5.3.22</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
<!--    <version>
  5.0.1
</version> -->
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
<!--    <scope>runtime</scope> -->
     <version>2.6.3</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
<version>19.0</version>
</dependency>




<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.2</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

</dependency>

  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
<version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency> 
    
    
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
<version>10.0.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>4.3.9.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
    
    
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.22</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
<version>1.18.20.0</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<!--  <version>2.6.4</version>  -->
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.6.4</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
<version>5.9.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>common-tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
<version>10.0.23</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
    
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>


</build>
```

I was trying to start it with the server, but now that I have decided to keep the embedded version, I start it as a java application.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. You imported the project in Eclipse and how are you trying to start it? Regarding the question for jar files: Usually you do not have to copy jar files manually. The pom,xml might be helpful.

Comment: I run it from the server. First I remove the project from the server, then I clean the server, re-add the project to the server, then go to the project and run it with the server. I added the pom.xml file

Comment: YO need to build the war file and deploy that to the server. However you are using Spring Boot why deploy to the server at all. That being said your dependencies are quite a mess, mixing jars from different versions of a framework, using incompatible versions... Plugins as dependencies

Comment: As M. Deinum said you don't need a dedicated server, Spring Boot comes with an embedded server. To run it, see this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677808/how-to-run-spring-boot-web-application-in-eclipse-itself

Comment: my professor told me to use eclipse, so i was forced to abandon spring, using embedded server, it gave me other errors, i posted the question and someone told me these errors depended on the server referencing a project version not updated and therefore I had to redeploy it. On another page in the forum, I read that it is always better to have the external server and not the internal one, so I put it external. I have 290 jar files in my maven dependencies and I don't know which ones to keep and which to delete.